# I get : Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: 'Could not instantiate class named (null)'

Tags: ios, iphone, crash

I have a collection view inside which i load cell which have been designed in xib and i am using auto layout. Same cells are used in multiple collection views. After creating collection view i am doing following

```
UINib* nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"Cell1" bundle:nil];
[collectionView registerNib:nib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell1"];
```

I am creating cell in following way

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 NSInteger count = [_products count];
    Cell1* cell = (Cell1*)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell1" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if(_products != nil)
    {
        [cell updateCell:_products[indexPath.item % count]];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

But i am getting following crash when it goes to dequeue the cell. Note that this crash doesn't occur always, it happens like once in 100 times. I have checked IBOutlets and constraints, they are all proper.

> Application Specific Information:
>   *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: 'Could not instantiate class named (null)'
>
> Last Exception Backtrace: CoreFoundation
>   0x00000001840402d8 __exceptionPreprocess + 132 libobjc.A.dylib
>   0x0000000195cbc0e0 objc_exception_throw + 56 CoreFoundation
>   0x0000000184040214 +[NSException raise:format:] + 124 UIKit
>   0x0000000188fa3394 0x188aa8000 + 376 UIKit
>   0x0000000188fa3200 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 340 UIKit
>   0x0000000188e2dcb4 -[UILabel initWithCoder:] + 700 UIKit
>   0x0000000188fa3544 0x188aa8000 + 808 UIKit
>   0x0000000188fa34e4 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 712 UIKit
>   0x0000000188fa3200 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 340 UIKit
>   0x0000000188d80d40 -[UIView initWithCoder:] + 624 UIKit
>   0x0000000188fa3544 0x188aa8000 + 808 UIKit
>   0x0000000188fa34e4 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 712 UIKit
>   0x0000000188fa3200 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 340 UIKit
>   0x0000000188d80d40 -[UIView initWithCoder:] + 624 UIKit
>   0x00000001891504ac -[UICollectionReusableView initWithCoder:] + 52
>   UIKit                          0x0000000189150738
>   -[UICollectionViewCell initWithCoder:] + 60 UIKit                          0x0000000188ed95a8 -[UIClassSwapper initWithCoder:] + 232 UIKit
>   0x0000000188fa3544 0x188aa8000 + 808 UIKit
>   0x0000000188fa3200 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 340 UIKit
>   0x0000000188ed90b0 -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:] + 124 UIKit
>   0x0000000188fa3544 0x188aa8000 + 808 UIKit
>   0x0000000188fa34e4 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 712 UIKit
>   0x0000000188fa3200 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 340 UIKit
>   0x0000000188ed8538 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1096 UIKit
>   0x0000000189142b80 -[UICollectionView
>   _dequeueReusableViewOfKind:withIdentifier:forIndexPath:viewCategory:] + 792 UIKit                          0x000000018243de58 0x182408000 + 220760 Clubcard                       0x000000010016dcbc
>   -[CollectionDataSourceSecond collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:] (CollectionDataSourceSecond.m:91)

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: why do you cast SubDepartmentProductCollectionViewCell to Cell1 ?

Comment: Sorry, corrected it. Missed out changing name.

Comment: when the crash happened is nib nill ?or cell nill ?

Comment: I am not able to get that. Its production crash and i am getting crash log from the crash reporting tool.